# Why do I still get "unresolved external symbol" error after adding the reference to the test project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I created a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. I added two files to it: `MyClass.hpp` and `MyClass.cpp`. Then I created a test project and added the original project as a reference.

If I doubleclick on the reference in the test project, I can see `MyClass`. But if I try to run the tests, I get this error:

```
MyTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct MyRef __thiscall MyClass::SetData(struct Data)" (?SetData@MyClass@@QAE?AUMyRef@@UData@@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall MyTest_SetData_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@MyTest_SetData_Test@@EAEXXZ)
```

What do I wrong? Why is `MyClass.cpp` not compiled, even if it is in the referenced project?
I can build the original project without error. I only get the link error, when I try to build the test project.

---

I came across [this question about unresolved external symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but it did not solve my issue. This is a Visual Studio specific problem.

If I add `MyClass.cpp` to the test project manually, then it works. But I do not want to do that for each file, because my project may have many more cpp source files, not just this one. I would like to make it work using the "references" feature.

When I created the test project, I selected the original project as a reference.

Comment: Do you have an implementation for 'MyTest_SetData_Test::TestBody(void)' in your 'MyClass.cpp'

Comment: @MHAlikhani Yes, I do have an implementation

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Please reopen this question. The linked question did not solve the issue.

Comment: How did you add the project reference?  Is is a "shared project" reference?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I just simply selected the original project as a reference, when I created the test project. What is the difference between shared and simple references? The original project is not listed under "shared projects", and I can't find out, how to make an existing project shared.

Comment: Project references are usually used for .NET assemblies and related things, and not very often with native code.  This older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115974/what-are-visual-studio-project-references) may shed some light.  A [shared project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#shared-project-references) will compile into each project that references it.  Or you can go the traditional DLL route.

Comment: Maybe related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515089/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-in-vs-unit-testing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811378/cppunittest-link-to-windows-application

Comment: @IterAtor if the original project MyClass is dynamic library, then add in your test project properties ->Linker->input : MyClass.lib and in Linker->general->Additional Library directories the path to your lib

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579172/undefined-reference-to-class-constructor-including-cpp-file-fixes

Answer (score 5):

Adding project B to project A as a reference basically just assures that project B is compiled whenever project A is compiled.

You need extra setup:

1. make sure project B builds as a library (and not an executable)
2. consider two paths accessible from both projects. This will be where the project B library will be installed. This comprises of two things:

   - the binary (static library is the simplest setup)
   - the library headers
3. on compilation of project B you need to install both the resulting binary and the headers to these paths. For this you can make a post build step that copies the necessary files: Properties » Build Events » Post-Build Event

   Alternately just use project B's build folder and source location.
4. in project A:

   - add the header path to the include paths: 
     Properties » C/C++ » General » Additional include directories
   - add the library to the list of libraries to link: 
     Properties » Linker » Input » Additional dependencies
   - add the binary path to the linker library search 
     Properties » Linker » General » Additional Library Directories

Comment: also make sure you add the library to the list of libraries to link; just adding it to the linker search path isn't enough

Comment: @OMGtechy oh yeah, forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something to the previous comments/answers:

You didn't mention if you build your reference project as a static or dynamic library.

This can be set by going to the project's Properties->General->Configuration Type

Note that if you select `Dynamic Library (.dll)`, your symbols (such as `MyClass::SetData(struct Data)`) will not be exported by default and you'd need to add the `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2019)